# Slow Keys breaks Key repeat settings

Tags: macos

New MacOS user here.

First of all, after reading a couple of threads on the subject, it is a common occurrence for some people to mention "get used to macos, it's not windows, deal with it" - but that's besides the point.

Coming from Windows, I was actually really surprised how much I could customise my Mac to fit my workflows and habits. Some of them required third party apps, but the customiseablility has definitely been there thus far and I love it.

Now, here is what I did. I do not like the delay in the caps lock, having to very shortly pause on it doesn't work for me as I type quite rapidly. Looking up the fix was very easy. All I had to do was to go to **System Settings > Accessibility > Keyboard > Slow keys** and drag the slider all the way to 0. Now, caps lock activates instantly when I press it which is great.

However, this seems to "break" the *delete* key. Deleting text is now painfully slow. The usual fix for that is to go to adjust the **Key repeat** settings to very fast, however when Slow Keys is activated it doesn't work anymore.

How could I keep my Caps Lock to "instant" whilst also getting very fast text delete?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Why not just switch Slow Keys off altogether?

Comment: @Tetsujin because then the Caps Lock isn't instant anymore, it has a small delay before "capturing" a tap on it and switching the caps lock. Having Slow Keys on, but setting the "Slow Keys Speed" to 0 makes all of my keystrokes instant.

Comment: try https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10467/how-to-increase-keyboard-key-repeat-rate-on-os-x and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411531/increase-keyrepeat-speed-in-macos-big-sur I can't really test how it works for capslock because I never use it; I actually have it switched off so I don't ever hit it accidentally.